# After function is run, how to stop duplication of displayed results on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Via a drop down box, the below function runs. It will place images of friends the user is connected to onto the page, via `#containerFriendsConnected` . But if the user selects "Connected Friends" multiple time from the drop down box, the user images are replicated.

Say the user has 2 friends, if you click the drop down box option 3 seperate times,the page will repeat the 2 friends and show them 3 times each on the page (6 images in total).

I presume I need to add some simple if statement that stops this? Something like

```
For (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                                        });
```

This is where I'm stuck.

FUNCTION THAT REPEATS IMAGES

```
                function FriendsConnected() {
                    $('#containerFriendsRejected').empty();
                    $('#containerFriendsPending').empty();
                    $('#containerFriendsRequestSent').empty();
                    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
                    var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

                    var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
                    query.include('toUser');
                    query.include('SentTo');
                    query.include("myBadge");
                    query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
                    query.equalTo("status", "Connected");

                    query.find({
                        success: function(results) {
                            var friends = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                friends.push({
                                    imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
                                    friendRequestId: results[i].id,
                                    username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
                                    userId: results[i].get('toUser').id


                                });


                            }
                            var select = document.getElementById("FriendsConnected");
                            $.each(friends, function(i, v) {
                                var opt = v.username;
                                var el = document.createElement("option");
                                el.textContent = opt;
                                el.value = opt;
                                select.appendChild(el);
                            })

                        _.each(friends, function(item) {
                             var wrapper = $('<div class="portfolio-item-thumb one-third"></div>');
                            wrapper.append('<img class="responsive-image friendImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />'+ '<br>');
                            wrapper.append('<div class="tag">' + item.username + '</div>');
                            $('#containerFriendsConnected').append(wrapper);
                            });

                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Maybe you just need to empty the DIV before you append to it?

Comment: If you can hide the button then hide it on click. You can also just add a class to the button when clicked and then only run the add friends function if the button does not have that class. Many ways to achieve this, add the code for dropdown change event

Comment: @Barmar is that inefficient since it will still run the entire code block when it doesn't need to

Comment: WHere did the answer go?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using .empty();

At the following point

```
$('#containerFriendsConnected').empty();

 _.each(friends, function(item) {
                             var wrapper = $('<div class="portfolio-item-thumb one-third"></div>');
                            wrapper.append('<img class="responsive-image friendImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />'+ '<br>');
                            wrapper.append('<div class="tag">' + item.username + '</div>');
                            $('#containerFriendsConnected').append(wrapper);
                            });
```